Higher DC coil voltage
I am using a JMACD-26XM  TE Connectivity relay for a DC voltage control circuit.
I just realized that the measured voltage at the site is 28.5VDC, therefore, higher coil power rating. Will it burn the relay? The relay is not in continuous use.
I cannot change the design.

Welcome! If you can't change the design, you are out of options.

The relay will work within 5 minutes, do you think there is any problem?

The risk sounds low, but instead of asking strangers on the internet, I would advice you to go directly to the source and ask the manufacturer. They should have data to back it up.

many thanks!!!!!!!!

The relay is rated up to 125 C ambient. The manufacturer might be able to give you a higher voltage rating based on a lower max temperature ambient.

Thank you, before that, I also tried running at 27.3VDC, the results were still good

Checking with mfg. is always best, but having used these quite a bit in the past I doubt you'll see a problem.

Lacking any additional information (which is not recommended), I would derate the maximum operating temperature to 110°C, based on the 16% higher than nominal power dissipation.
You could always add a series resistor, but that would have to be evaluated carefully, especially given the large changes in coil resistance with temperature.
ESCC Detail Specification No. 3601/002 indicates that relays of similar type have a maximum coil voltage of 32V, with no reference to derating.
